# I am getting this error after executing the python and sql code to send variable to database

Tags: python, mysql, sql-server, pyodbc

**Code** :

```
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO [MAaaS_db].[dbo].[LIVE_ALARMS]([SITEID] ,[ALARMTYPE] ,[ALARMCODE]  ,[ALARMNAME] ,[REMARK]) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)""",('sr', 'sendernumber', 'sendernumber', 'cutsubject','cutsubject'))
                    cnxn.autocommit()
```

**Error**:

> ('22018', u'[22018] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid
>   character value for cast specification (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')

Answer (score 0):

Is [SITEID] numeric (integer) field?
You have provided string value 'sr' here... That might cause the error

Comment: sr is an integer

Comment: Do you have SQL Profiler ? So you can trace what is actually running on SQL Server by filtering your database